# Superposition principle

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble finding the general solution for this question:

> Show that $a=(1,1,0)^T$ and $b = (-3,3,-2)^T$ are particular solutions to the system 
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&-5\\ 1&-4&-6\\ 3&2&-4 \end{bmatrix}X=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-3\\5\end{bmatrix}$$
>   and find the general solution.

The book says the general solution is

> $$\begin{align}X & = a && + t(b-a) \\&= (1,1,0)^T && + t(-4,2,-2)^T\end{align}$$

but how did they get that as the general solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the general solution, is to apply  elementary row operations on the augmented matrix 
$$\hat{A}=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}2&-1&-5&1\\ 1&-4&-6&-3\\ 3&2&-4&5 \end{array}\right]$$

After some row operations, the given system is equivalent to the following system $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\ 1&0&-2\\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}X=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

So, the general solution is given by $$y+z=1, x-2z=1 $$ which can be written as $$(x,y,z)=(1+2z,1-z,z)=(1,1,0)+z(2,-1,1)$$

To match with your book, put $z=-2t$.

Note that $a$ and $b$ corresponds to the particular value of $t=0$ and $t=1$ respectively. Hence they are particular solutions.